How to Pass MongoDB new Date() Function as Raw in Aggregation Query
I want to pass a MongoDB function (new Date()) as raw in an aggregation query from C#. I expect that in my MongoDB view, the result should look like this:
$and: [
  {
    create: {
      $lte: new Date()
    }
  }
]

However, when I try to use new BsonDocument, literal, BsonJavaScript, or BsonString, I always end up with something like:
$lte: "new Date()"

or
$lte: Code("new Date()")

Since my aggregation pipeline is quite large, I don't want to send everything as a JSON string. I simply want to have new Date() without quotation marks in my view.
Here’s a part of my current code:
var pipeline = new List<BsonDocument>
{
    new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument("$and", new BsonArray
    {
        new BasicDBObject("create", new BsonDocument("$lte", new BsonDocument("new Date()"))),
        new BasicDBObject("end", new BsonDocument("$gte", new BsonDocument("new Date()")))
    }))
};

Can anyone help me adjust this so that new Date() is passed correctly?

Your C# API/library is going convert it all to JSON when the pipeline/query is sent to MongoDB anyway. What are you trying to do with new Date()? Why not just C#'s new DateTime? Like new BsonDocument("$gte", new DateTime()). Anyway, you can use $$NOW in aggregations to get the current time.

so when u use new DateTime() it will be run and compiled, so view will cointain date, when it was run (when migration has been run)

Have you considered using "$$NOW" or "$currentDate"?

No, i cannot use DateTime.Now, because it will be saved to view as constant date - as you can see in your own output.
i used $$now function - it works as expected, so thanks Joe!

you can use lazy initialization: new BsonDocument { { "create", () => DateTime.UtcNow, true } } to fix it

As mentioned in the comments, you should use a c# DateTime class. You can see result if you render the pipeline:
        var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<BsonDocument>()
            .Match(new BsonDocument("$and", new BsonArray
            {
                new BsonDocument("create", DateTime.UtcNow),
                new BsonDocument("end", DateTime.UtcNow)
            }));

        // render for driver version 3.0:
        var registry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
        var rendered = pipeline.Render(new RenderArgs<BsonDocument>
        {
            SerializerRegistry = registry,
            DocumentSerializer = registry.GetSerializer<BsonDocument>()
        })
            .Documents
            .Single()
            .ToString();

Output:
{
    "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "create": {
                    "$lte": {
                        "$date": "2024-12-09T20:19:34.97Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "end": {
                    "$gte": {
                        "$date": "2024-12-09T20:19:34.979Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

as an option, it's possible to configure date as lazy:
    new BsonDocument
    {
        { "create", () => DateTime.UtcNow, true }
    },

